# What is the easiest way to make pixelated maps with obstacles in pygame?

Tags: pygame

So I have been trying to create a game with a small map that moves with the player. If the player goes to a wall, the camera also stops. No scrolling. If you want to discover an area, you go to it. And there are many obstacles. the map should be sort of the cafeteria from among us. I tried using tiled, but… It is not beginner friendly. Making a separate file is okay with me. Thanks in advance.

Full code:

```python
'''
Imports
'''
import os
import random
import sys

import pygame
import pygame_textinput
from pygame.locals import *

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

'''
Basic Stuff for Pygame
'''
pygame.init()
display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 640))
pygame.display.set_caption("AMOGUS")
gameIcon = pygame.image.load('icon_of_the_game.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(gameIcon)

'''
Variables
'''
fps =600
ai_move_speed = 2
player_changeable_name = pygame_textinput.TextInputVisualizer()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
white = (255, 255, 255)
WINDOWHEIGHT = 580
WINDOWWIDTH = 740

'''
Game State Variable
'''
menu = "menu"
game = "game"
ending_ani = "ending_ani"

'''
Functions
'''


def menu():
    print("In Proggress")


def game():
    print("In Proggress")


def ending_ani():
    print("In Proggress")


'''
Images
'''
special_character = random.randint(1, 5)
if special_character == 1:
    imposter = pygame.image.load('sus1.png')
    chooseable_var = random.randint(1, 4)
    if chooseable_var == 1:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus2.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus3.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus4.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus5.png')

    if chooseable_var == 2:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus5.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus2.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus3.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus4.png')

    if chooseable_var == 3:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus4.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus5.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus2.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus3.png')

    if chooseable_var == 4:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus3.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus4.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus5.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus2.png')

elif special_character == 2:
    imposter = pygame.image.load('sus2.png')
    chooseable_var = random.randint(1, 4)
    if chooseable_var == 1:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus1.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus3.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus4.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus5.png')

    if chooseable_var == 2:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus5.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus1.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus3.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus4.png')

    if chooseable_var == 3:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus4.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus5.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus1.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus3.png')

    if chooseable_var == 4:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus3.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus4.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus5.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus1.png')
elif special_character == 3:
    imposter = pygame.image.load('sus3.png')
    chooseable_var = random.randint(1, 4)
    if chooseable_var == 1:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus2.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus1.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus4.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus5.png')

    if chooseable_var == 2:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus5.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus2.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus1.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus4.png')

    if chooseable_var == 3:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus4.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus5.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus2.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus1.png')

    if chooseable_var == 4:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus1.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus4.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus5.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus2.png')
elif special_character == 4:
    imposter = pygame.image.load('sus4.png')
    chooseable_var = random.randint(1, 4)
    if chooseable_var == 1:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus2.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus3.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus1.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus5.png')

    if chooseable_var == 2:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus5.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus2.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus3.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus1.png')

    if chooseable_var == 3:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus1.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus5.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus2.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus3.png')

    if chooseable_var == 4:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus3.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus1.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus5.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus2.png')
else:
    imposter = pygame.image.load('sus5.png')
    chooseable_var = random.randint(1, 4)
    if chooseable_var == 1:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus2.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus3.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus4.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus1.png')

    if chooseable_var == 2:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus1.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus2.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus3.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus4.png')

    if chooseable_var == 3:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus4.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus1.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus2.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus3.png')

    if chooseable_var == 4:
        sussie1 = pygame.image.load('sus3.png')
        sussie2 = pygame.image.load('sus4.png')
        sussie3 = pygame.image.load('sus1.png')
        sussie4 = pygame.image.load('sus2.png')
hero = pygame.image.load('hero.png')


'''
Hero
'''
heroX = 100
heroY = 100
MOVESPEED = 2
moveRight = False
moveLeft = False
moveUp = False
moveDown = False
'''
Imposter
'''
ImpX = 50
ImpY = 500
imp_left = False
imp_right = True
down_val = 64
up_val = -64
default_mover = down_val
'''
Sussies
'''
Sussie1X = 0
Sussie1Y = 0
Sussie2X = 50
Sussie2Y = 50
Sussie3X = 100
Sussie3Y = 100
Sussie4X = 250
Sussie4Y = 250


'''
Main Script
'''
game_state = menu
while game_state == menu:

    display_surface.fill(white)
    display_surface.blit(imposter, (ImpX, ImpY))
    display_surface.blit(sussie1, (Sussie1X, Sussie1Y))
    display_surface.blit(sussie2, (Sussie2X, Sussie2Y))
    display_surface.blit(sussie3, (Sussie3X, Sussie3Y))
    display_surface.blit(sussie4, (Sussie4X, Sussie4Y))
    display_surface.blit(hero, (heroX, heroY))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # Change the keyboard variables.
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
                moveRight = False
                moveLeft = True
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = True
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w:
                moveDown = False
                moveUp = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s:
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w:
                moveUp = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s:
                moveDown = False
        else:
            pass

    if moveDown and heroY < WINDOWHEIGHT:
        heroY += MOVESPEED
    if moveUp and heroY > 0:
        heroY -= MOVESPEED
    if moveLeft and heroX > 0:
        heroX -= MOVESPEED
    if moveRight and heroX < WINDOWWIDTH:
        heroX += MOVESPEED

    if heroY == 0:
        heroY = 0

    if heroX == 0:
        heroX = 0

    if heroX == 740:
        heroX = 740

    if heroY == 580:
        heroY = 580

    if imp_right:
        ImpX += ai_move_speed
        if ImpX == WINDOWWIDTH or ImpX > WINDOWWIDTH:
            imp_right = False
            imp_left = True
            ImpY += default_mover
        if ImpY == 0 or ImpY > WINDOWHEIGHT:
            default_mover = up_val
            imp_left = True
            imp_right = False

        if ImpY == 0 or ImpY < 0:
            default_mover = down_val
            imp_left = True
            imp_right = False

    if imp_left:
        ImpX -= ai_move_speed
        if ImpX == 0 or ImpX < 0:
            imp_left = False
            imp_right = True
            ImpY += default_mover
        if ImpY == WINDOWHEIGHT or ImpY > WINDOWHEIGHT:
            default_mover = up_val
            imp_left = False
            imp_right = True

        if ImpY == 0 or ImpY < 0:
            default_mover = down_val
            imp_left = False
            imp_right = True

    clock.tick(fps)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Cafeteria: https://among-us.fandom.com/wiki/Cafeteria

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using separate files to use as your map :
just write down all the obstacles rectangular shape which is INSIDE that map and use that information to whatever collision detection action You need.

However, if you are a beginner I suggest making games with static   Viewport (exploring the map only moves the character), they're a lot easier.

*Share your code*, so we can help you.

Comment: sorry just saw your answer now. I shared the code in question. And how to use static viewport?